# Возможен ли disable для ссылки?

Tags: jquery, javascript

На странице присутствует ссылка:

```
<a href="#" id="SendRecord" disabled="disabled"><span>Записать</span></a>
```

Можно ли средствами JS сделать ее неактивной для события hover(CSS) и click(js)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="#" id="SendRecord" disabled="disabled"><span>Записать</span></a>

$('a[disabled]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('disabled-link');
});
```

Не проверял, но в теории должно работать, на класс disabled-link вешаете стиль с отключенными "ховерами".

Comment: С отключенными ховерками - это какое свойство CSS? Наверное, pointer-events: none

Answer (score 1):

[event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/): If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

Comment: Дело в том, что ссылка должна быть неактивная не сразу, а от результата ответа от Ajax.

Comment: И что вас смущает?

Comment: success: {
// как использоваться event.preventDefault() здесь для ссылки?
}

Comment: onclick на ссылку вешаете и снимаете действие по умолчанию. Можно еще стили поменять, чтобы было видно, что ссылка неактивна.

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, конечно нет. Этот метод поможет вам остановить события на ссылке.

Comment: Вот он, великолепный мегакод:

    $('selector').click(function(event) {
        if ($(this).data('disabled')) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });

После этого на нужных ссылках нужно будет просто выполнить `.data('disabled', true);`. Можно еще через `.attr()` сделать, реально прикрутив атрибут disabled, если сильно приспичит.